# Switch Statement for UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I know you cannot do a switch on a NSDictionary, but here is what I am trying to do I have a NSDictionary like such:

```
myDict = {"one":@["foo", "bar"], "two":@[@"see", "tee"]}
```

The acutely dictionary is longer and has more elements but you get the point.

I am not trying to switch what kind of cell to use in a UITableView depending on the key of the dict. So in an ideal world it would be

```
switch (myDict) {
        case "one":
            //do stuff
            break;
        case "two":
            //do stuff
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

How could I achieve this same thing?

Thanks for the help

Comment: switch statements are not compatible with strings.

Comment: What are you talking about? Of course you can use switch for strings

Comment: @spenf10 can you fix the wording on your question it makes no sense

Comment: Just switch on the key, you don't need to switch on the dictionary.